# Which cells to pick to get a pure sample of DNA without precise equipment?

Tags: biology, genetics

Normally when conducting DNA testing, I presume techniques are utilized to ensure you're just testing one individual's DNA from a sample, even if it is possible that sample was contaminated one way or another.

However, in a thing I'm writing, there's a character that is able to produce personalized medicine for another individual after ingesting a sample of that individual's DNA.

The catch is that they can't always have laboratory equipment to isolate someone's cells (and thus DNA) from contaminants with other DNA (like from bacteria or just other people's dead skin). They might have to make due from eating hair or licking sweat, and so on, but the more contaminant DNA there is in the sample leads to reduced efficacy in the medicine.

My question, for the most part, would be which cells are good targets to collect samples from in this instance that are unlikely to have someone or something else's DNA in the sample; excluding anything that requires special equipment to get to or decontaminate the sample.

And to a lesser extent, which are the bad targets that fall under the conditions of being relatively easy to obtain a sample of, but are likely to have a high amount of contaminants?

Comment: As this seems to be through ingestion, what DNA would be considered a contaminant? Would plant DNA interfere or DNA from animals (liked cooked food - though this would likely be fragmented)?

Comment: I would say any DNA not from the intended subject counts as a contaminant, animal or not. Though fragmented or otherwise damaged DNA would probably count as less of a contaminant than DNA from a living cell.

Comment: What level of technology do they have available. A bone marrow sample pre-industrial will kill the person faster than anything you are going to save them from.

Comment: For the setting, slightly more advanced than current tech. However, this is for non-ideal situations (hence the lack of specialized equipment) so I'd say any current tech that is reasonable to carry around in case of emergencies.

Comment: individual cells - it is not how it is done today, and no need to worry about that too much. contaminations can be sorted more on the side of reading DNA and stuff. use blood same as answers recommend, you need white blood cell for that as they have nuclei. Operating on individual cell level(sampling) with portable equipment is possible(needs microscope like device, which if we imagine a bit more advanced tech can be very small, for the task), but probably look for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab-on-a-chip stuff.

Comment: Does the character "ingesting" the person's DNA have a sterile mouth?  Otherwise the sample is likely to be contaminated by bacteria from their saliva. (As well as their own DNA.)

Comment: The character in GATTACA offers a blood sample for DNA identification because he suggested that the usual inside of the cheek swab might have been contaminated by kissing his partner (not that it would have mattered if it had shown up the other or both so a weak plot need).  Still today the GO-TO source is a swab of the inside of your cheek.

Comment: In regards to the "self-contamination" issue, the character's mouth is mostly sterile, but that's a good point I'll keep in mind. Though their own DNA can't be a contaminant by the necessity of the mechanics.

Answer (score 10):

Rather quickly you are going to have to question where we draw the line between "your DNA" and "other DNA."  It's clear on paper, but in practicality, its a hodgepodge mess.  For example, viruses inject themselves into our DNA to replicate.  Some have become permanent residents in our genetic code.

However, with all that side, blood would be a very powerful way of getting "pure" DNA.  Our bodies have evolved to use bleeding as a way to clean out wounds, so it would be unlikely that blood taken from a carefully made wound would be infected.  A sterile knife is probably very useful for this, but that's a far cry from laboratory equipment.  And given that our blood is full of nutrients and oxygen, we have a substantial interest in keeping foreign bodies out of it.  Failure to do so often leads to sepsis.

Comment: Since the question specifically asks "which cells", I would say "blood" is a misleading answer.  Blood is mostly water and red blood cells; red blood cells in humans (like other mammals) do not have nuclei or mitochondria, and thus do not have DNA.  There is DNA in white blood cells, but it takes a comparatively larger amount of blood to get a given amount of DNA compared to other tissues. Apparently quantity is less of a concern than purity, so I agree that blood is a good choice.

Comment: Can't make an edit that short, but you accidentally wrote "would" twice instead of writing "wound".

Comment: @TomášZato Thank you, fixed!

Comment: @brendan True, I found the value of it being a liquid "tissue" to outweigh some of the annoyances.  There are also blood borne pathogens, but there's going to be classes of diseases which affect any part of the body, so I figured it was fair game.

Comment: @CortAmmon having the blood sample may be an asset as you can test for all sorts of other antibodies and hormone imbalances due to genetic endocrine diseases and make 'medicine' that will fix those or use recombinant viruses planting 'medicine' that will fix the inherited diseases in all the blood donors cells.

Answer (score 4):

**You have to balance risk vs reward.**

You have to balance contaminations risk with the damage you do obtaining the sample. A simple blood sample should work fine, minimum damage, low contamination risk, failing that a adipose tissue sample will lower the risk even more. Both can be obtained with a simple needle.  Just sterilize wherever you put in the needle first, this reduces contamination risk but is also just a good practice overall. A portable syringe and some alcohol swabs is all you need to carry around.

Don't collect tissue from any part of the digestive tract or exterior of the body as they are covered in bacteria, the respiratory track also has a high contamination risk it is one of the main ways bacteria get into the body.  Use basic common sense, the person has obvious infection then you need to worry about a more sterile source, and again you will have to balance the benefit of say a bone marrow source vs the risk of infecting the bone marrow. There is also the extreme pains collecting a bone marrow sample has, not something you should ignore.

Answer (score 3):

Brain or gonad cells would probably be the best, in terms of keeping bacteria and their DNA out.  Both are well-protected from infection by necessity.  The blood-brain barrier is only able to be penetrated by a few diseases, all of which show obviously neurological symptoms.  If the person you want to sample seems healthy, their brain cells are very likely uncontaminated.  Same thing with the gonads, both ovaries and testes.  They're highly controlled because foreign DNA, like from a bacterium, can screw up gamete production.

One big problem with both of these is getting the sample without seriously hurting the person.

I think your next best bet is inside their teeth, especially if those teeth are healthy.  Not much can get through enamel, and what does leaves obvious evidence; don't use rotten teeth.  This is not as good, from a purity standpoint, as the brain however.  Your teeth a pretty porous when they're forming, and will pick up foreign matter in your childhood.  Scientists were able to find out where [Otzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96tzi) the Iceman grew up by examining pollen trapped in his teeth.  I don't know how much pollen they found or how much your magic pharmacist can handle, but it's something to consider.  On the plus side, anyone with a rock or other blunt object could knock out a tooth.

Comment: I appreciate knowing that those are options, but I'm not entirely sure how one would obtain samples from those places without specialized equipment (or as you said, seriously injuring the subject). 

Granted, I can see obtaining a sample from the tooth by knocking it out with a blunt object or something, which doesn't count as "specialized equipment" but falls back on the seriously injuring thing.

Comment: getting to the DNA in teeth will destroy the tooth, and mammals don't get any replacements.

Comment: @John True, unless you get a baby tooth I suppose.  Though I don't know if baby teeth are as contamination-free as adult teeth.  Maybe they're softer than adult teeth, I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

**Considering DNA per volume and absence of contaminant organisms, your best bet is sperm.**

1. /The spermatozoon is characterized by a minimum of cytoplasm and the most densely packed DNA known in eukaryotes. Compared to mitotic chromosomes in somatic cells, sperm DNA is at least sixfold more highly condensed./[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spermatozoon) 
   You will get the most DNA per unit volume with sperm.
2. Semen (containing sperm) is sterile before emission and so free of bacterial contaminants or DNA from other organisms.
3. Sperm has the drawback of being haploid.  Sperm from a given male will contain DNA only from that male, but the DNA has undergone meiotic recombination.  The haploid, meiotically recombined genome of the spermatozoon does not contain any DNA not present in the male of origin, but the DNA in the sperm will be arranged differently from that of somatic cells in the male.
4. Using sperm as the DNA source limits collection to males, as females do not have sperm.
5. It is possible to (repeatedly) retrieve and ingest semen and sperm from a human male without damaging the male.  The male might even cooperate in this endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

### Saliva is a nice clean DNA sample.  Ditto cheek cells.  You don't need anything more complex to get.

Since these are on the inside of the body, they won't have other DNA from touching things.  You do need to make sure the mouth is reasonably clean before taking a sample (small amounts of food aren't an issue but large amounts of food or someone else's bodily fluids should be removed first.

All the genetic genealogy companies use saliva (spit into a clean collection container with preservative) or cheek cells (with a clean cotton swab put into a plastic case).  This includes companies doing whole genome testing and medical DNA testing.  You can use blood but it's not required.

Bacteria contamination is simply not an issue with DNA testing.  Sure, you can have bacteria or other infectious substances degrade your sample but the testing equipment has no trouble separating out the bacteria (etc).  Presumably your character has a way to separate out her/his own DNA from the analysis.

Your character can get a sample from a prolonged kiss with the subject (depending on how much DNA is needed; the vials of spit one gives can be used for multiple tests and the subject gives that much as a backup, even with a swab, [one swab can be used for multiple tests](https://forums.familytreedna.com/forum/general-interest/dna-and-genealogy-for-beginners/14587-how-many-tests-will-the-two-swab-samples-support) and you can even [get DNA from an old licked postage stamp](https://thefamilycurator.com/how-to-preserve-and-test-old-letters-for-grandmas-dna/)).  Get some tongue in there for science.  A little scrape of the teeth doesn't hurt.

Another method would be to give the target a water bottle to drink from then have the character drink the backwash.

Of course, if the target wants this testing done, providing a sample is as easy as one-two-spit.

A poor sample would be from the outside of someone's body because it has a risk of being contaminated by someone else's DNA.  I would especially avoid the hands and the feet (if the subject goes barefoot or wears sandals).  Not to mention that outer layers of skin and hair and etc are not good sources of living DNA, no matter how clean they are (the little bulb you sometimes bring up when you pull out hair can have good DNA).

Sperm is not a viable choice for collection because it only has a random half of each chromosome other than the sex chromosomes and then either the X or the Y from that.  It's good enough for a basic DNA match for forensics, but it won't give you the medical information you're looking for, though you can make predictions about the alleles if you analyze enough sperm cells from the same man.

Tears and urine only work if they have skin cells in them (like saliva does).  But they and other bodily excretions (like earwax) can work some of the time.  [Sweat won't have usable DNA](https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/14/17352044/sweat-science-health-biomarkers-forensics).

**So make it easy.  Spit and gentle scrapings of the inside of the mouth.**